# Vertices limitation in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, vbo, vertices

I have an OpenGL scene with thousands of vertices and would like to pass them as VBOs/IBOs.
Executing the glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES, &maxVertices) command reveals a limitation of 2048 max amount of vertices, despite the fact I have a recent video card.
In addition to that, an array in C is limited to an int, hence 32k vertices max.

How can I work around these limitations to anyway display all my objects ?

Comment: An array in C is limited to an int?

Comment: When I use something else than an integer in the brackets (e.g. MyArray[double_variable]), it tells me "Array subscript is not an integer".

Comment: `double`s can't be an array index, but `long` can be. `int` and `long` are both integers. It's rare for `int` to be as small as 16 bits on platforms with recent videos cards too.

Comment: What OpenGL implementation and platform/compiler is this?

Comment: You must be developing on exceedingly old hardware to get a 2048 size on `GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES`.

Comment: Not really, on an iMac from 2010...

Comment: `MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES` and `MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES` are only suggestions, they are not hard limits. [The OpenGL spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf) (page 329) states that if you keep your sizes/ranges below those limits, you will get optimal performance. If you exceed those suggestions, you may get reduced performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES` constant only applies to the `glDrawRangeElements` call and even then values larger than that will surely not make `glDrawRangeElements` slower than `glDrawElements`. It is not a good idea to manually split your batches into smaller parts, as batches should be as large as possible and draw calls as few as possible. Just forget about this value, it has no real meaning anymore.

And by the way, I'm quite sure your int can hold values much larger than 32k, as on modern platforms (at least those with a graphics device that supports VBOs) an int should be at least 32bits wide (and therefore be able to hold values like 2G/4G). Although on an embedded device (using OpenGL ES) you might still be limited to 16bit vertex indices.

Comment: Thanks, but an array in C only accepts an integer as index, hence 32k elements. How can I reach your 2M then ?

Comment: @Laurent Like I (and  awoodland's comment) said, an `int` being only 16 bits wide (which is equivalent to a +/-32k range) in C is very unlikely on a modern platform, where it should usually be at least 32 bits wide (meaning a +/- 2G range, not only 2M). Where did you get this information about an `int` only being 16 bits?

Comment: Thanks, it starts slowly to make sense to me ! I don't know where I get this int limit to 32k, maybe in the past indeed. I am developing on Cocoa/Xcode. Let me try with int anyway then.

Comment: @Christian Rau: Can you confirm that GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES and GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES are not used anymore? What else would you use to decide when to split up draw calls? What would you use in OpenGL ES? See my question [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/142490/how-and-when-to-split-draw-calls-in-opengl-and-opengl-es).

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES just tell you the most vertices that can be passed to a single call of glDrawRangeElements? Is there a reason you can't split your scene into bits and render the bits one by one?

Comment: So basically I could have a VBO of 30k elements for example and pass it piece by piece using glDrawRangeElement ?

Comment: Yep, I think so. See the docs: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawRangeElements.xml To avoid the possible reduced performance, you just have to give it bounds for where the indices you're using lie.

Answer (score 1):

Divide your total number of vertices by 2048 and create than many VBOs

```
void glGenBuffersARB(GLsizei n, GLuint* ids)
```

So n would be (total / 2048)+1 and ids would be a GLuint array containing (total / 2048)+1

Comment: Thanks. Should I then do the glBindBuffer, glBufferData, glVertexPointer and glDrawElements for each single VBO, or is it sufficient that I run them once ?